# Autosuggestion not working in SXA 1.8.1

Tags: sxa, content-search

I'm using sitecore 9.1.1 and SXA 1.8.1.

i'm trying to use the OOTB Autosuggest but i always get the below error.

> { "Message": "An error has occurred.", "ExceptionMessage": "Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object.", "ExceptionType":
>   "System.NullReferenceException", "StackTrace": "   at
>   Sitecore.XA.Feature.Search.Controllers.SearchController.GetSuggestions(QueryModel
>   model)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.b__3(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location
>   where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__1.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__6.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__6.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__6.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__6.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__3.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()"
>   }

Any idea what might be missing?

Comment: Welcome to the site :-)  We need you to always include error messages and stack traces as text (not screenshot), or the search engines will not have a change to find anything. Also - in general - troubleshooting questions such as this are better suited for our Community Forums or our Slack Chat.

Comment: What search provider are you using? How is the Search Box configured (there is a dropdown for suggestions mode)? Does the search works?

Comment: @ Dawid Rutkowski i'm using SOLR, for the search box configuration i set the suggestion mode to "show predictions", the other two modes uses the SXA/Search/Results API and it's working fine.

Comment: Seems like you need a sitecore support ticket.